# Reading file in C++ giving weird characters after the actual file content

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm trying to read a JSON file into a char array/char *. But whenever I read a file, it give some weird character  after the actual file content like so:

> {"Image": "myImg.jpg"}ts;C:\Ureßr

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

This is my current code:

```
char* read_file(const char *file)
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if (infile)
    {
        infile.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
        int len = infile.tellg();
        infile.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);
        char *data = new char[len];
        infile.read(data, len);
        return data;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Try checking the value of your `len`

Comment: after last symbol in your string insert zero-symbol

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName yes the length is incorrect. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So-called "C-Style" character strings need to be [nul-terminated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344633/356108) in order to work with any of the standard functions, such as are used for displaying them.

In order for your `data` buffer to conform to this, you need to increase the allocated buffer size to allow for this terminator character, and also make sure that the last element is actually the `nul` character (zero or `'\0'`).

```cpp
char* read_file(const char *file)
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    if (infile)
    {
        infile.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
        int len = infile.tellg();
        infile.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);
        char *data = new char[len + 1]; // Add space for the nul terminator ...
        infile.read(data, len);
        data[len] = '\0';               // ... and set the last element to "nul"
        return data;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Without the proper terminator, a call like `cout << data` to display your character array will keep outputting characters until it does (by chance) find a zero byte in the buffer it is given (or, maybe it will crash before it does so). The 'weird' characters you are seeing represent the data that happen to be in memory, just after the `data` buffer you have allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char *data = new char[len];
    infile.read(data, len);
```

This reads everything from the file into a `char` buffer. And nothing more. Nothing else.

If you attempt to print the contents of this `char` buffer using any means that expects to see a C-style character string, you are going to forget a small detail: C-style character strings are terminated by a `'\0'`, which this code neglects to add to the read contents, so whichever C or C++ library function you're using to do this, will simply look for the `'\0'` character. And keep looking. And keep loking. And keep looking.

You simply need to `new` an additional byte up front (`len+1` instead of `len`), and drop a `'\0'` in there, after the read file contents.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I explained in my last paragraph.